# json deserializing and serializing in windows mobile 6.5

Tags: windows-mobile-6.5

In my windows mobile application i would like to deserialize and serialize JSON objects.
Have searched but could not find any.Could anyone please let me know if there is any API support or how can i do it if manually needs to be done.

Please share your valuable suggestions.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest https://github.com/lloyd/yajl: it has windows build instructions and uses only ANSI C. I've in the past built it for Windows Mobile 6 projects, and it works well. The examples show how you can parse from a byte array, and it also support serializing a structure to a character array.

Comment: Hey dont we have any api support in C# for JSON parsing.I find this difficult :(

Comment: Ah,  are you using the .Net framework? You should be able to use http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json-net.aspx or http://code.google.com/p/jsonexserializer/. Look at the C# section of http://www.json.org/ for a more complete list of available libraries. The most recently updated library is http://code.google.com/p/fluent-json/, and its pretty small.

Comment: Hi Femi i am using .Net compact framework for windows mobile.Could you please let me know if there is any api for mobile 6.5

Comment: Try http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json-net.aspx: it supports the .Net compact framework.

Comment: JSON.NET for compact is painfully slow for me sometimes.. It got 2 seconds to desirialize a 40 kb thing..